# page redirection in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I want to redirect the page after login succesfully completed. but the problem in this code is, if i give wrong input, it also go to home page. so i removed this statement 'window.location = home.php'. what could i do now? does anyone help me guys?

```
<script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#reg_form').parsley();
                    $('#reg_form').on('submit',function(event){
                        event.preventDefault();

                        if($('#reg_form').parsley().isValid())
                        {
                            $.ajax({
                                url:"db.php",
                                method:"POST",
                                data:$(this).serialize(),

                                beforeSend:function(){
                                $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
                                $('#submit').val('submitting the value');
                                },
                                    success:function(data){
                                        $('#reg_form')[0].reset();
                                        $('#reg_form').parsley().reset();
                                        $('#submit').attr('disabled',false);
                                        $('#submit').val('submit');
                                        $('#message').html(data);

                                    }

                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

**db.php**

```
<?php

//user login
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
        $email =  $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_register where email ='$email' AND password = '$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        echo "login successfully completed";

    }
    else 
    {
        echo "login failed";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its better to pass flag value that login successfully or not from server side.

Like:

If you will write below code:

```
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        echo 1;

    }
    else 
    {
        echo 0;
    }
```

And then in ajax call you can check data

```
 $.ajax({
                                url:"db.php",
                                method:"POST",
                                data:$(this).serialize(),

                                beforeSend:function(){
                                $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
                                $('#submit').val('submitting the value');
                                },
                                    success:function(data){
                                         if(data==1){
                                        window.location = home.php
                                        }
                                       $('#reg_form')[0].reset();
                                        $('#reg_form').parsley().reset();
                                        $('#submit').attr('disabled',false);
                                        $('#submit').val('submit');
                                        $('#message').html(data);

}
});
```

I hope my answer helps you.

Comment: can you tell me what issue you faced?

Comment: i replaced my code which you given..but again i will not go to another page..it shows login scuccesfully completed in the login.php page

Comment: can you please redirect after start the success. please see updated code

Comment: thats good.. please give upvote if its work for you. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please always use the sessions in such login scenarios. you can set the session value if the login information is correct. Then check the session value in home.php, redirect the page from home.php to login page if session value is not correct. use the following code.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    echo 1;
    $_SESSION["is_logged_in"]="1";

}
else 
{
    echo 0;
    $_SESSION["is_logged_in"]="-1";
}
```

Now in "home.php" check whether the user is logged in or not.

```
if ($_SESSION["is_logged_in"]==-1){

     //redirect back to login page

}else if ($_SESSION["is_logged_in"]==1){
     //do nothing

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your php file

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    echo json_encode(array("status"=>1,"msg"=>"login successfully completed"));

}
else 
{
    echo json_encode(array("status"=>0,"msg"=>"login failed"));
}
```

and in ajax success check for the status from data as

```
 if(data.status){
      // success code and redirect code

   }else{
       // failed
   }
```