# User login form using jquery ajax not working properly, not directing to any page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, mysqli

I'm trying to create a login form  with jquery ajax by taking user details from "reg"  table in database. But It'snot working .I want to enter anothe page called menu.php after login. Nothing is showing when i click login button Can anyone help please

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){

$('#loginForm').submit(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
             $.ajax({
                url: "logindata.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    username: $("#username").val(),
                    password: $("#password").val()
                },
                success: function(response)
                {
                    if(response == 1)
                    {
                        window.location.href = "menu.php";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#errorMessage").html("Attempting Login...");
                    }
                }
            });

           });
    });
            </script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<center><b>Login</b></center><br>
                <form name="loginForm" id="loginForm"  action="" method="post" align="center">
       Username:    <input type="text" name="username" id="username"  /><br><br>
       Password:    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"  /><br><br><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Sign In" />
                </form>
```

Mysql query page:

```
<?php
$conn =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project");

$f="SELECT * FROM reg WHERE uname='" . $_POST["username"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$f);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if( $row[0] > 0 )
 {
        echo 'true';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'false';
    }
    ?>

?>
```

Comment: not working is not enough .. what is the output of `console.log(response);` and for redirect you can use `window.location.href = "menu.php";`

Comment: If you do a var_dump() of $_POST when attempting to log in as a test user, what do you get?

Comment: im getting username ... the person loggin in

Comment: also your code will not even listen to the `submit` event untill you prevent the default form redirect.. you need to use `$('#loginForm').submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault();`

Comment: also wrap your submit event in  `$(document).ready(function(){  // your submit event here  })`

Comment: i did all the thing you said ...but its not working..thanks anyway :)

Comment: again and again ..Please don't use words **NOT WORKING** to describe your issue .. this is tons of assumes in programming .. comment all your php code in php file and just echo out anything .. then comment the if statement on ajax success function and just `console.log(response)` .. and see (tell us) with the output

Comment: sorry , the thing is..there not showing any error...when i used console... it didnt show anything..when i click submit button nothing is happpenng... it is no directing to anything..but when i var_dump..th username is shown

Answer (score 0):

In your response you have "Login Successful" or "Failed To Login", there's no "true".
Also take care about SQL injection.

Comment: i corrected that.. actually i accidentl clicked undo before copying code.. its still not  working though:(

Comment: Look in the DevTools (F12) in Network tab what does your php script returns. Also check console if there isn't some error in js.

Comment: Instead of `$row[0] > 0` use just `$row` because mysqli_fetch_assoc returns either array with row or null.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have not return true/false you have return string. Instead of echo "Login Successful"; echo true and false and at the end write exit.

Answer (score 0):

Will you please try with below code:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
     {
            echo 1;
        }
        else
        {
            echo 0;
        }
   }
```

Ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#loginForm').submit(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
             $.ajax({
                url: "logindata.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    username: $("#username").val(),
                    password: $("#password").val()
                },
                success: function(response)
                {
                    if(response == 1)
                    {
                        window.location = menu.php;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#errorMessage").html("Attempting Login...");
                    }
                }
            });

           });
        </script>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54303475/page-redirection-in-jquery/54303656?noredirect=1#comment95428577_54303656)

Comment: Please define`id` attribute into your form. it is missing.
<form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" action="" method="post" align="center">

Comment: Will you please try with `mysqli_num_rows($result)` instead of `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Please see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
change in jquery
$('#loginForm').submit(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
             $.ajax({
                url: "logindata.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    username: $("#username").val(),
                    password: $("#password").val()
                },
                success: function(response)
                {
                    if(response == 1)
                    {
                        window.location = menu.php;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#errorMessage").html("Attempting Login...");
                    }
                }
            });

           });
```

change in php

```
<?php
$conn =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project");

$f="SELECT * FROM reg WHERE uname='" . $_POST["username"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$f);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if( $row[0] > 0 )
 {
        echo 1;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 0;
    }
    ?>
exit;
?>
```

Comment: tried it dear..not working though..thanks for the help:)